# Securing RESTful api with Spring Security

Tags: spring, security, rest, authorization

I am coding an backend RESTful webservice in which I need spring security authentication. 
For now I was using standard form-login style. But I dont want to do this that way. I need fully restful authentication.

I was looking for some tutorial etc. in google, but found actually nothing productive. There were many of them, but none actually worked or were finished.

Can someone explain this to me, how should the authorization process look like? Maybe some example code, self-made tutorial etc?

Will be thankful! :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had the time to watch it yet since it is a new video from Spring, but I think that would be a good one:

Webinar: Security for Microservices with Spring and OAuth2

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yePeJ6NDZQk

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my [working application](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-security-rest).  The application has been written to support fully stateless authentication and authorization for a REST application.  The concepts used have been in production for at least 8 months now, without any reported problems.  In general this application shows how you could do the following:

1. Use a standard REST request for authentication, something along the lines of `POST:https://www.server.com/authentication:{"principal":"joe.user","secret":"strongsecret"}`.
2. Use Spring Security for full authentication and authorization.
3. Replace the default Spring Security authentication token infrastructure (that depends on `HttpSession`) with a cache based infrastructure (could be an in-memory or persistent cache) to provide exactly the same semantics as `HttpSession`, such as, session expiry, sliding expiration, etc.
4. Pass authentication token back and forth between the REST server and client in HTTP headers.

If you are using Ehcache or any other caching framework in your app already, you should be able to just take the sample code and plug it into your app to stand up a REST API.